# Add value to existing Sass variable

Tags: variables, sass

Say I have a variable `$colours: red`

Is there a way to add another colour to the already existing `$colours` variable so, I end up with a variable `$colours: red blue` from a function that exists further down the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append the new value, you use the [`append()`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#append-instance_method) function

```
$colours: (red);
$colours: append($colours, blue);
```

Comment: Also you could simply re-assign the value of the variable as: `$colours: $colours blue;`